# Modifying Custom Post Type after registration (will it affect content?)

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, hierarchical

I have a CPT (defined in `functions.php`) that I have set to as non-hierarchical. A lot of content has already been uploaded into the database.

If I change the definition to `'hierarchical' => true`, will the change affect any of the posts in that CPT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will not. It changes just the interface in the post editor: you get the page attributes box to select a parent.

All existing post have already a value for the parent: `0`. You can find it in the `post_parent` property of each post. The only thing that changes now is the ability to change that value.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I wanted to hear! Thanks a lot for the response.